# AWS user just for creating RDS snapshots

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, administration, amazon-rds

I have a requirement to give access to a user to create snapshots of RDS instances for backup and restore, is this possible in AWS. Also, I need the same user, needs to version s3 buckets, is this possible??

Answer (score 1):

I think that should be possible.

Here is the set of RDS Snapshot permissions.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAM.ResourcePermissions.html

This is possible the permission set you are looking for for restore. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot.html

I would guess you might need to grant Describe.  I would create a user and then apply the permission sets and test for least possible permissions you can grant to the user.

These are the permission sets for S3 Objects.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html

When you say Version S3 buckets you normally set this once on a bucket then it will version any object changes applied to it. The permission set above will then just limit there access to the objects in that bucket.